# How do I move my troops across water?

Tags: imperator-rome

During a recent war I successfully invaded an Sardinia by setting one of my fleets to the "naval landing" order. Now that the war is over I want to shift my legions back to Italy.

How do I do this? Simply giving a move order does not seem to have any effect. I have a fleet set to the naval invasion order and the move order is from a port to another port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the troops near the sea.

Put the boats in the sea near the troops.

Select the troops and click on the boat to order them aboard.

[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOK1TK8HKxQ)